# Replacing existing rows with new ones causes duplicate key exception

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

everyone.
I have problem replacing existing rows in table with new ones. I use JPA and PostgreSQL DB. I'm trying to delete all existing rows and then create new ones, but receive exception:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_destination_pk". All these actions are inside single JTA transaction. It seems that JPA doesn't delete rows before inserting, but I receive no delete exception... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the Hibernate `Session.flush()` method to flush (execute the SQL of) the deletes before saving/adding the new entities.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about flush(), but I guess It finishes DB transaction. Am i right? I don't want to delete, not being sure that new rows are good.

Comment: calling flush() doesn't finish the transaction (although committing the transaction does implicitly flush()), it just makes Hibernate execute SQL to bring the db into the same state as the session.

Comment: I would like to know what do we have to call flush() explicitly after the delete and before the insert, though?

Comment: @Glide because Hibernate doesn't guarantee that SQL statements are executed in the same order as objects are removed from/added to the session. This particularly occurs if the objects are being managed by a collection. By putting in a `flush()` call, the deletes are pushed out to the database before the new entities are added.

Comment: @araqnid so is the convention flush() after every hibernate statement? When is calling flush() required?

Comment: @Glide Hibernate will generally auto-flush to ensure that *queries* see the correct persisted state. Updates are ordered to avoid foreign key violations. But updates are not ordered to avoid unique key failures, in general. So if you're updating some table that has a unique key, and you would have to do the underlying SQL in a specific order, you may need to use `flush` to keep in control.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the unique constraint as `deferrable initially deferred`

Comment: I thought of that at first as well but I don't think it would help here. From the description it seems that it's actually JPA not sending the deletes before sending the inserts. The only situation where this would help is when JPA would send the deletes **after** sending the inserts.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That doesn't matter within the same JTA transaction though.